# memory leak raspbian stretch vs jessie

Tags: python, linux, memory-leaks, raspberry-pi, kill-process

I created a script in python, on a raspberry pi raspbian Jessie.
i now have the exact same script running on a new release raspbian stretch.
root     24545 14.1  2.4  30568 23168 pts/1    S+   23:48   0:03 python Tlh/Hints/Main.py

it is using around 14.1% of the CPU usage, and it is using around 2.4% memory
after a few hours the script memory keeps increasing on the stretch release. Untill the Linux OS kill's that process because it is consuming all the free resources.
While running on a Jessie release it keeps on running for days without a problem.

how can i start debugging to find where that leak is? and what exactly is going wrong?

and what has changed between jessie and stretch? because it was running perfectly.

Comment: the python versions may be different?

Comment: both are using python 2.7

Comment: Python uses garbage collection

Comment: i also thaught that it does, but apparently somehow the GC is turned off ? can that be?

Comment: Python version in Raspbian Jessie : 2.7.9 while on Raspbian Stretch it is: 2.7.13. I will try to go to 2.7.9 as well and see if the issue is fixed.

Comment: I went back to raspberry Jessie, using python 2.7.9, the problem was gone instantly. still have no explanation for this

Comment: Were you able to fix it? @BikLander

Comment: @DavidSidarous unfortnunatly no i didn't put time in it. it is still using the old linux version.